# Jquery - JSON.parse error

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code:

```
var data = JSON.parse(error.response.data)
```

But it is throwing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

This is what inside error.response.data:

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
     "dto.IsInternal": [
      "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'. Path 'IsInternal', line 1, position 86."
    ]
  }
}
```

How do i fix?

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse()`, directly use `error.response.data`

Comment: Hi adam78 actually you can use error.response.data direct instead of parse JSON.